# Loading DataTable from DataSet with correct column widths and format

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, vsto

I was wondering how to adjust to column widths to fit the width of the data and set values to 2 decimal places in C# while using Visual Studio Tools for Office when loading from a DataSet. The code I am using to populate the DataTable is below:

```
public DataTable myData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myDataSet.Tables.Contains("TableName"))
            {
                 return _myDataSet.Tables["TableName"];
            }
            else 
            {
                 return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Looking in the wrong place. The width and format are problem of the user interface element where you want to display your table data

Comment: But you can modify the width and format through code as well though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is an in-memory representation of a set of data. It has no width or format properties.

If you are populating a, for example, [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) from the `DataTable` then this `DataGridView` or, more specifically, its rows or columns, have such properties. For example:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;

dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

[How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :MSDN